# Meaning of VAR=* in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I saw the following (to start a nodejs express web server) and I can't find documentation about the `*` in this:

```
prompt>> DEBUG=* command
```

This sets `DEBUG` to a temporary value in the command's environment, but what value? I tried `export DEBUG=*` on a line of its own and `DEBUG` ends up being a star:

```
prompt>> export DEBUG=*
prompt>> printenv DEBUG
*
prompt>>
```

So may there isn't anything special about it, and the nodejs express web server looks to see if `DEBUG` is "*". Are there situations ( such as a different history of commands) where the `DEBUG=* command` would result in `DEBUG` not being a star in the command's environment?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with BASH - From BASHES POV, "DEBUG" is just an environment variable and can take any value its assigned.

Comment: My question is not about the variable name, it is about the meaning of the statement "var=*" which is certainly bash specific, because although it appeared to be assign a literal star to var, the star often has special meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man bash` details all the expansions that are performed during variable assignments:

> The text after the = in each variable assignment undergoes tilde
>   expansion,  parameter  expansion,  command  substitution,  arithmetic
>   expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

**None** of those expansions will change the value of `DEBUG=*`.

If *pathname expansion* were performed during variable assignment, it would cause `*` to be replaced by a list of files.  But, *pathname expansion* is **not** in the list above and, consequently, will not alter the `*`.

In sum, `DEBUG=*` sets the value of `DEBUG` to a literal `*`.